# How to add Paragraph on image using python pillow and align text at center?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to write text on the image, the text is long and not printing all the text on the image

So I want to get the text at center and write a paragraph on the image line by line when the size of the image gets outside the image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import textwrap

with open(".txt", "r") as f:
    W, H = (500,500)
    for line in f:
        singleline = (line)
        img = Image.open("bb1.jpg")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        font = ImageFont.truetype('demo2.ttf',20)
        l = textwrap.wrap(singleline, width=40)
        w, h = draw.textsize(singleline)
        draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2),singleline,font=font, fill = 'black') 
        img.save(singleline+'.jpg')
```

This is Image that I am getting as output 
[Please see the image that I am getting as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13D8s.jpg)

The text is not getting at the center and not all text is showing on the image it is going outside of the image